# Grails multi datasource domain issue

Tags: database, grails, connection, datasource

I have a project which tables spread between 2 datasources.
I'm configuring the code to access table as per 3.3.6 topic in grails documentations
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M2/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments

Everything seems to be ok, but I got the following error

> Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: br.com.fisgo.Provider
>
> Caused by MappingException: Association references unmapped class: br.com.fisgo.Provider

Any idea on why do I get this error?

Regards.

I'll try it out.
It won't be that simple because Company domain links back to Provider
It will just require more efort

```
class Company {
    String name
    String cnpj
    String email
    Address address
    Phone phone
    String registration
    String source

    Set provider = new HashSet<Provider>()

    static hasMany = [provider: Provider]
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use newer docs, e.g. http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSourcesAndEnvironments

It looks like you're trying to link across datasources. This isn't possible since each `DataSource` has a separate `SessionFactory`, and they cannot work directly together. The same problem happens when you use Hibernate and a NoSQL GORM plugin.

You can mimic it easily enough though. Given a domain class Foo that needs a reference to `Provider`, you can persist the foreign key and look it up on-demand (and this is really what Hibernate does for you when you join between two domain classes):

```
class Foo {
   Long providerId

   Provider getProvider() {
      providerId ? Provider.get(providerId) : null
   }
   void setProvider(Provider provider) {
      providerId = provider.id
   }
   static transients = ['provider']
}
```

Since Groovy treats getter/setter pairs as a property, you would use it like a "real" link:

```
def foo = ...
def bar = foo.provider.bar
```

Comment: Hi, I am currently facing the same issue. Did this solution work for you? Does it have any performance problems? Is there also possible to cache the "provider" so that you don't have to get it every time from the db? Thanks!

Comment: This works, but is really onerous when you get past one or two classes and moots the time saving features of the framework. Is this something that was addressed in the 3.x release of Grails?