# Grails 3.0 multiple datasources

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am new to grails and I am currently using grails 3.0. I was trying to have the one-to-many relation between two tables across different databases. I have referred almost all the links and grails documentation, but couldn't figure out if this scenario is at all possible. I have sample code written, which works perfectly if the two tables from two different databases are independent. i.e. there is no relation/mapping or references. I see the data has been saved properly in each table through the sample. 
If I try to map the tables with say one-to-many relation (typical Book-Author domain class example), it fails. I get the `mapping exceptions`. I also tried the suggested workaround of overriding the `get` and `set` methods. 
Are there any links or sample code which will guide me? Here is my code without `getter` and `setter`:

```
class Book {
    Long   id
    String title
    String author
    Users user
    static constraints = {
        title(blank: false)
        author(blank: false)
    }
}
class Users {
    String username
    String address
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    static constraints = {
        username(blank: false)
        address(blank: false)
    }
    static mapping = {
        datasource 'lookupusers'
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? How have you configured your Datasoruces? You need to provide more information.

Comment: I am using MySQL and created the two databases on the same servers. I see no issues with the datasources as the above code works perfectly if I remove Users object reference from Book class or use default database. I have read in few forums that relation between tables across different databases is possible only through the get and set method in domain class. Here are few links I referred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282879/grails-multi-datasource-domain-issue or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768667/grails-gorm-domain-association-across-two-datasources

Comment: Error I get is this -> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table book refers to an unmapped class: org.example.Users